# Variable assignment avoids an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I have two pieces of recursive code, intending to recursively print out half of the array until we get to arrays of array length 1. The code without variable assignment runs infinitely while the code with variable assignment behaves as expected.

Any clues why this is the case?

*Runs infinitely, **CAREFUL***

```js
function half(arr) {
  halfway = Math.floor((arr.length) / 2)
  console.log(arr)
  if (arr.length > 1) {
    half(arr.slice(0, halfway));
    half(arr.slice(halfway));
  }
  return
}

half([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
```

*Does not run infinitely*

```js
function half(arr) {
  halfway = Math.floor((arr.length) / 2)
  console.log(arr)
  if (arr.length > 1) {
    var a = arr.slice(0, halfway);
    var b = arr.slice(halfway);
    half(a);
    half(b);
  }
  return
}

half([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
```

I thought that maybe some kind of mutability might be at play here but I can't imagine how there would be run on effect. I thought that we were passing what is effectively a whole new array into the function every time it gets called...

Comment: `var halfway = ...` -- Currently `halfway` is a global variable that is being clobbered by the recursive calls.

Comment: Can anyone answer why the first code does not output [1,2,3,4,5] ?

Comment: @TusharShahi Because the visible effects of a function call are queued, but never get the chance to appear because the infinite loop doesn't end.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol but other stuff gets printed right? And [1,2,3,4,5] should be the absolute first thing to get printed. But doesn't?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it lacks `var`, `let` and `const`, **`halfway`** has global scope, as if you wrote `window.halfway`. As a result, all recursive calls modify and use the same single variable.

In the **1st function** the value is changed in the first recursive call before it can be used in the second recursive call. In my testing this actually led to a kind of Stack Overflow error (or rather a Maximum call stack size error), very appropriate for this site :-).

In the **2nd function** the value is used twice before the recursive calls start, and then it gets modified by both after each other.

Issue solved by using `const`:

```js
function half1(arr) {
  const halfway = Math.floor((arr.length) / 2)
  console.log(arr.toString())
  if (arr.length > 1) {
    half1(arr.slice(0, halfway));
    half1(arr.slice(halfway));
  }
  return
}

function half2(arr) {
  const halfway = Math.floor((arr.length) / 2)
  console.log(arr.toString())
  if (arr.length > 1) {
    var a = arr.slice(0, halfway);
    var b = arr.slice(halfway);
    half2(a);
    half2(b);
  }
  return
}

const data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
half1(data);
console.log("------------------------")
half2(data);
```

Final note: the whole problem would have been detected and prevented by the JS compiler if you had put [`'use strict';`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) on top of your code. I don't really like how clumsily this directive works (why does putting a "dead and unused" string on top of your code have such a special and far-reaching effect?), but we'll have to make use of what we can get.